# Two Jpanel and button

Tags: java

I have a `JFrame` which contains 2 `JPanels`. The first contains: `JTextField` and a `JButton` 'Add'.  This `JButton` should get what is written in the `JTextField`.

The next `JPanel` contains a `JComboBox` that displays the data from the `JTextField`, which was provided via the button.

All of the code works well.

However, when I do the insert via the button, the data inserts in database OK but the `JComboBox` doesn't contain the data.

I currently must close and open the jframe and then I find the data displayed in the combobox.

I don't know what can I do to show the data immediately in the `JComboBox` when I add a new name in `JTextField` of `JPanel1`.

Comment: We can't help you unless we see the code. Having said that I suspect you need to revalidate/repaint.

Comment: Please post your code, as Grammin said.  As you can also see, your post was edited numerous times for grammar and clarity.  Please verify that these edits accurately reflect your problem and try to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, something like this?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Wut {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPanel panel_1;
    private JComboBox comboBox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Wut window = new Wut();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Wut() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        textField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            if (!textField.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    comboBox.addItem(textField.getText().toString());
                                comboBOx.setSelectedItem(textField.getText().toString());
                                textField.setText("");
                            }
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnAdd);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel_1.add(comboBox);
    }

}
```

When you click the Add button, it adds whatever is in the text field to the combo box.

Comment: yes but the combobox dosent' diplay the new insert automaticaly i must close the interface and open again then i find the new data in it

Comment: one contains jtextfield and button add

Comment: @cisco.nat Yes, that's what's happening in my code. If you see `panel.add(textField)` and `panel.add(btnAdd)` - those are going into a `JPanel` called `panel`.  `panel_1` contains the `comboBox`.  But are you saying you want the combo box to set its value to most recent entry?

Comment: look i have 2 panels in frame